# TimeZone shifts using TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timezone, sql-server-2008-r2, utc

I have incoming hourly data (spanning 5 years) with timestamps recorded in CST or EST. I want to store this in my database in UTC time.

Is there a way for me to convert from CST/CDT/CPT or EST/EDT/EPT to UTC using TSQL?

Answer (score 2):

mI would recommend you store these as DATETIMEOFFSET to preserve the timezone information.

If you need to display then as UTC Dates then you can use SWITCHOFFSET

Comment: Of course, this requires being able to calculate the offset for each piece of hourly data, which, over the course of 5 years will be different. [This MSDN blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/03/18/using-time-zone-data-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) has a sketch of an accurate (if complex) solution.

Comment: Why does it?  Surely you can store it as datetimeoffset complete with the offset it came in on then use SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(mydatetimeoffsetcolumn, '00:00') AS myUTCDate to get the date out in UTC

Comment: I'm assuming here that the timestamps come in without the offset. If they have the offset, it's no issue.

Comment: OK but,  If they come in with no offsets you would have to know which timezone the file came from otherwise you are screwed no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine is datetime in row in EST or EDT:

> [Since 2007, the local time changes at
>   02:00 EST to 03:00 EDT on the second
>   Sunday in March and returns at 02:00
>   EDT to 01:00 EST on the first Sunday
>   in November, in the U.S. as well as in
>   Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone).

Then apply `DATEADD()`

Mb my source code better explains what I mean:

```
declare @t table(dt datetime)

insert @t values ('2011-07-06T10:00:00'), ('2011-01-01T00:00:00'), ('2011-03-12T00:00:00'),
    ('2006-07-06T10:00:00')

select b.dt
    , CASE
        WHEN b.dt between b.[edt_start] and [edt_end] 
            THEN DATEADD(HH, -5, b.dt)
        ELSE DATEADD(HH, -4, b.dt)
    END

    , CASE
        WHEN b.dt between b.[edt_start] and [edt_end] 
            THEN '-05:00'
        ELSE '-04:00'
    END

from
(
    select a.dt
        , DATEADD(HH, 2, CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, a.march) = 1 
                THEN a.march 
            ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 15 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, a.march), a.march) 
        END) [edt_start]

        , DATEADD(HH, 2, CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, a.november) = 1 
                THEN a.march 
            ELSE DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, a.november), a.november) 
        END) [edt_end]
    from
    (
        select t.dt
            , YEAR(t.dt) [year]
            , CAST(CAST(YEAR(t.dt) as varchar(4)) + '03' + '01' as datetime) [march]
            , CAST(CAST(YEAR(t.dt) as varchar(4)) + '11' + '01' as datetime) [november]
        from @t t
    )a
)b
```

Comment: The difference between `GETUTCDATE()` and `GETDATE()` is useful only for determining the offset at the moment the query is run. It isn't of much help with historical data, as the offset can vary depending on the whim of local government, DST, etc.